# Show progress R2WinBugs

Tags: r, for-loop, progress, winbugs, r2winbugs

I am doing several Bayesian analyses using R2WinBugs so I can put them in a for-loop. It works perfectly, R calls WinBugs, then the simulation starts and when it is done the results are saved and the next analysis starts. 
When I normally use WinBugs, without R, I can monitor the simulations already done in the update screen so I roughly know how fast it is going and how long it will take to finish. My question is: Is there an option with R2WinBugs, or maybe a different package, to call WinBugs in for loops and still force WinBugs to show the progress made?

I hope my question is clear :)

Comment: do you want to see the progress of winbugs or your for loop? It would be very easy to add a line in the loop to tell you which analysis you are doing. If there isn't an option in r2winbugs, you might have to edit the source code

Comment: The progress of WinBugs.

Comment: You could specify `debug=TRUE`? Also, I think runjags uses progress indicators, but you would have to adapt your code. Depending on your model, there are a few native R packages, such as MCMCglmm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it is possible using R2WinBUGS. You can set `debug=TRUE` to follow the simulations in WinBUGS itself, but it will mess up your `for` loop as you will then need to quit WinBUGS manually after each model run.

BRugs shows the same progress as a WinBUGS log file,... as in you can run the model check, initialise parameters, compile the model and update the simulations with output printed in the R console.